# (rails) hidden form elements not giving values to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, hidden-fields

I have the following form:

```
<% form_for(:tag, :url => {:action => "post_tag", :id => @photoID}) do |form| %>
  <%= error_messages_for(:tag) %>
  <% if @errors then %>
  <%= @errors[0] %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= form.select(:user_id, @userHash) %></p>
  <p><%= form.hidden_field(:xpos) %></p>
  <p><%= form.hidden_field(:ypos) %></p>
  <p><%= form.hidden_field(:width) %></p>
  <p><%= form.hidden_field(:height) %></p>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit Tag" %>
<% end %>
```

But none of the values are filled in the controller. I know the values are all full in the view because I can see they have the correct values in Firebug. In the controller, I am trying to access them like `params[:xpos]` for the `:xpos hidden_field`. Is this correct???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `logger.debug params.inspect`. I have a sneaking suspicion you will see `params[:tag][:xpos]` there :)

You have passed a name to form tag there (`form_for(:tag, ...) do |form|`), it will wrap all fields constructed as `form.field(...)` in a hash identified by the passed name ("tag", in this case).